# T- SQL Re-usable Error Trapping Code

Tags: t-sql

I have this error trapping code to write error to a log table. I have to repeat it after ever begin try, end try. I don't want to use a loopback server. I'm using a stored procedure with transaction with rollback if any of the 48 tables have an error on insert or update. It's making my code 2000 lines. Is there a way to make it a class, as there would be in other programming so I don't have to re-paste the same code in my script so many times?

sql server 2008r

```
            insert into powercampustest.dbo.ADDRESSSCHEDULE (
            zip_code, 
            address_line_1, 
            address_line_2, 
            address_line_3, 
            city, 
            state, 
            county, 
            alternate_fax, 
            email_address, 
            main_fax, 
            address_type, 
            --SEQUENCE_NO, 
            CREATE_OPID, 
            CREATE_TERMINAL, 
            REVISION_OPID, 
            REVISION_TERMINAL, 
            PEOPLE_ORG_CODE, 
            PEOPLE_ORG_ID, 
            PEOPLE_ORG_CODE_ID, 
            NO_MAIL, 
            STATUS, 
            RECURRING, 
            APPROVED,
            CREATE_DATE,  
            CREATE_TIME,
            REVISION_DATE,
            REVISION_TIME)
            SELECT 
            ZIP, 
            ADDRESS1, 
            ADDRESS2, 
            ADDRESS3, 
            CITY, 
            STATE, 
            (SELECT top 1 CC.CODE_VALUE from [powercampustest].[dbo].[CODE_COUNTY] CC, [Bridge_test].[dbo].[PEOPLECHANGES] UC where CC.[LONG_DESC] like '%' + UC.[UCOUNTY] + '%'), 
            FAX, 
            UEMAILSCT, 
            FAX, 
            --COALESCE(UADDRTYPE, N' '), 
            'PERM', 
            --COALESCE(SEQUENCE_NO, 1), --sequence_no, is identity, it should increment
            COALESCE(CREATE_OPID, N' '), 
            COALESCE(CREATE_TERMINAL, N' '), 
            COALESCE(REVISION_OPID, N' '), 
            COALESCE(REVISION_TERMINAL, N' '),
            COALESCE(PEOPLE_CODE, N' '), 
            COALESCE(PEOPLE_ID, N' '), 
            COALESCE(PEOPLE_CODE_ID, N' '), 
            COALESCE(N' ', N' '), 
            COALESCE(N' ', N' '), 
            COALESCE(N' ', N' '), 
            COALESCE(N' ', N' '),
            COALESCE(CREATE_DATE, GetDate()),  
            COALESCE(CREATE_TIME, GetDate()),  
            COALESCE(REVISION_DATE, GetDate()), 
            COALESCE(REVISION_TIME, GetDate())  
            from Bridge_test.dbo.peoplechanges
            WHERE        (Processed is Null)
        END TRY 
        BEGIN CATCH 
            SET @flag = 'true'
            INSERT INTO @LogErrorsTable
            (
                [Error_Number],
                [Error_Message],
                [Error_Severity],
                [Error_State],
                [Error_Procedure],
                [Error_Line],
                [UserName],
                [HostName],
                [Time_Stamp]
            )
             SELECT ISNULL(ERROR_NUMBER(),0),
                    ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'NULL Message'),
                    ISNULL(ERROR_SEVERITY(),0), 
                    ISNULL(ERROR_STATE(),1),    
                    ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),''),            
                    ISNULL(ERROR_LINE(), 0), 
                    SUSER_SNAME(), 
                    HOST_NAME(), 
                    GETDATE()           
        END CATCH
```

Comment: SQL doesn't have classes. Why are you using more than one try catch block?

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: You could make it a stored procedure, rather than an insert, less lines one place to change it all so sort of like a class.

Comment: I'm using more that one try catch block because I don't want the transaction to stop on the first error, there are 35 tables so I want to get errors on all of the tables so that testing goes faster.

Comment: I tried another method using an autonomous transaction with a linked server for loopback and that is one way, but the admin doesn't want to add a lined server.

Comment: how would I make it a stored procedure, rather than an insert? Would it be to make the error logging code a function or stored procedure and pass the current query to it.